# Acceleration physics in Java does not slow down or stop

Tags: java, swing, game-physics

I've made a physics engine which contains acceleration, but when I try to make the object stop, it neither slows down or stops. It seems that the `if(deaccelerating) {...` never gets executed, I've tried a lot of methods, but none of them ever worked...

```
public class Acceleration {
    
    public float rateOfVelocity = 0.125f;
    public float rateOfAcceleration = 2;
    
    public int alternateRateOfVelocity = 1;
    public int alternateRateOfAcceleration = 2;

    public boolean accelerating;
    public boolean deaccelerating;
    
    public boolean alternateAccelerating;
    public boolean alternateDeaccelerating;
    
    public boolean loopedOnce;
    
    public void accelerate(float max, float min) {
        if(accelerating) {
            if(rateOfVelocity < max) {
                while(rateOfVelocity < max && !loopedOnce) {
                    rateOfVelocity*=rateOfAcceleration;
                    System.out.println(":)");
                    loopedOnce=true;                
                }
            }
            if(rateOfVelocity >= max || !accelerating){
                deaccelerating=true;
                System.out.println(deaccelerating);
            }
        }
        if(deaccelerating) {
            if(rateOfVelocity > min) {
                while(rateOfVelocity < min && !loopedOnce) {
                    rateOfVelocity/=rateOfAcceleration;
                    loopedOnce=true;
                }
            }
        else if(rateOfVelocity <= min) {
                deaccelerating=false;
            }
        }
    }
    public void alternateAccelerate(float max, float min) {
        if(alternateAccelerating) {
            if(alternateRateOfVelocity < max) {
                while(alternateRateOfVelocity < max && !loopedOnce) {
                    alternateRateOfVelocity*=rateOfAcceleration;
                    loopedOnce=true;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(alternateDeaccelerating) {
            while(rateOfVelocity > min && !loopedOnce) {
                alternateRateOfVelocity/=alternateRateOfAcceleration;
                loopedOnce=true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The physics gets used here-

```
public class DisplayContents extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    Thread run;
    Acceleration a = new Acceleration();

    float x=0,y=0;
    public boolean updateSpeed;
    
    public void startThread() {
        run = new Thread(this);
        run.start();
    }
    public DisplayContents() {
        
        this.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                    a.accelerating=true;
                    updateSpeed=true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                    a.accelerating=false;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
            });
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D draw = (Graphics2D) g;
        draw.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        draw.fillRect((int)x, 0, 100, 100);
        draw.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean loopedOnce = false;
        while(run != null) {
            repaint();
            a.accelerate(4, 0.125f);
            a.loopedOnce=false;
            while(updateSpeed&&!loopedOnce) {
                x+=a.rateOfVelocity;
                loopedOnce=true;
            }
            loopedOnce=false;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: I can't provide a Minimal Reproducable Example, as most of this is important code.

Comment: For a 1D situation, `if (accelerating)` would be better served by something like `if (acceleration > 0)`. Same for decelerating: `if (acceleration < 0)`. Further, your `deaccelerating` is only ever set to `true` in one place: the `if(rateOfVelocity >= max || !accelerating){` block. The `!accelerating` is always `false`, so that leaves `rateOfVelocity >= max`. Note that the loop before will only run once _ever_ (`loopedOnce` is never set to `false`), so the preceeding code will only change `rateOfVelocity` from `0.125` to `0.25` once _ever_. The end lesson: Use a debugger.

Comment: Notihing to do with your question, but: 1) NEVER use `dispose()` on a Graphics object passed to the paintComponent(...) method. Only dispose of object that you create. 2) All Swing components should be created on the EDT. The the frame and your LAF should all be done in the invokeLater()

Comment: @Rogue does using the Coverage option in Eclipse count?

Comment: Coverage utilities tell you if you have dead code, using a debugger tells you how the code behaves (and provides fine-tuned control over the execution of it). So no, they're nowhere near equivalent. A debugger will let you pause your running code at a specific line, look at the values held in variables, and make a determination for the behavior you observe (e.g. how an `if` statement isn't being called).